# When can a mathematician have $3$ friends?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

At a mathematics convention there are $n$ mathematicians. Each one has $3$ friends (friendship is symmetric). For what values of $n$ is this possible?

Comment: Is friendship reflexive?

Comment: @GitGud, I would assume it's irreflexive.

Comment: Reading the title alone on the mainsite my reflexive answer was "at a mathematics convention"...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For all even $n$ except $2$.

$n$ cannot be odd because if there are $k$ friendship-pairs, we must have $2k=3n$ (by counting person-pair incidences in two ways).
Also, clearly $n=2$ is impossible.

If $n>2$ (or $n=0$)  is even, arrange $n$ mathematicians in a circle and assume that everyone is friend with their left and their right neighbour and additionally with the one diametrically opposite.

Answer (score 2):

Base case $1$ if you have $4$ people make them all know each other.

Base case $2$ if you have $6$ imagine you have two columns of $3$ people
and make each person know every person in the opposite column.

Now for the general case if you have $4n$ people seperate them in $n$ groups 
of $4$ people and apply case $1$

If you have $4n+2$ people apply case $2$ for $6$ people so now you are left with $4n -4= 4(n-1)$ people. And the previous can be applied.

Comment: I have posted that, for an appoarch using an inductive way of thinking. Of course the case where $n$ is odd is dealt as Hagen von Eitzen has argued.